# Problems using tr1::regex with unicode strings

Tags: c++, regex, compiler-errors, tr1

```
    std::wstring str(L"something");
    std::tr1::wregex rx(L"something");
    std::tr1::wcmatch res;
    std::tr1::regex_search(str, res, rx);
```

This fails to compile with the error:

```
error C2784: 'bool std::tr1::regex_search(const std::basic_string<_Elem,_StTraits,_StAlloc> &,const std::tr1::basic_regex<_Elem,_RxTraits> &,std::tr1::regex_constants::match_flag_type)' : could not deduce template argument for 'const std::tr1::basic_regex<_Elem,_RxTraits> &' from 'std::tr1::wcmatch'
```

Comment: Beware that compiler support for `<regex>` in GCC is still very limited -- you might be able to compile, but not link, unless you have a cutting-edge version.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be using `wsmatch`, which is for `wstring` iterators, not `wcmatch`, which is for `wchar_t*`.

Comment: Wouldn't `wsmatch` be for `wstring`, not `string`?